# Any jquery plugin for labelling x/y points on Image?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am curious to know if there is any jquery plugin for labelling any image with respect to some x,y points? or any other way to do this?
Requirements: a line, and then a description div/label

Any kind of suggestion or help will be appreciated.

Comment: It wont be posible to edit an image directly with a JQuery plugin.

Comment: The only way you'd be able to do this with JQuery/JS is to load the image into a canvas, add the lines then export the image: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/923885/capture-html-canvas-as-gif-jpg-png-pdf